# What about hidden things?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, deuteronomy

The secret things belong to the Lord our God, but the things revealed belong to us and to our children forever, that we may do all the words of this law.

Deuteronomy 29:29

What would these hidden things be? Was there something being discussed among the people that there were no explanations for Moses to make comments in this regard?

I know it's a rhetorical question but is there any way to probe the nature of this? It would be details that the Torah does not cover such as how God created things, we only have that things came into existence, not how. Anyway, is there any discussion about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mefarshim (commentators) who discuss the idea of "secret things".

The Ibn Ezra [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.29.28?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en):

> The reference is to one who serves idols in secret.

> BELONG UNTO THE LORD OUR GOD. Its meaning is that his punishment is in the hands of God, and the Lord will exact punishment from him. However, if the sin was committed in public there is an obligation on us and our children to do in accordance with that which is written in the Torah.

The [Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.29.28?lang=bi&with=Chizkuni&lang2=en) builds on this idea and says it refers to:

> “sins committed in the privacy of one’s home, (which could not be witnessed and brought to court) will be taken care of by the Lord our G-d;” this had to be stated specifically in light of what we read in verse 18 about individuals who feel safe from punishment for their personal sins in periods when the community at large is Torahobservant.

The Chizkuni says the revealed things refer to the sins commited in public:

> והנגלות, ”but the sins committed publicly, etc,” dealing with deliberate sins committed in full view of the public must be dealt with by the judiciary by both you and your children, as otherwise such phenomena cannot be eradicated from your midst. This law becomes effective from the moment the Jewish people will cross the river Jordan. From that moment on their acceptance of the covenant with G-d meant that each individual Jew shared in the responsibility for the conduct of each fellow Jew. From that moment on we also became responsible.

The Shadal, in Sefer Yesodei HaTorah similary [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.29.28?lang=bi&with=Sefer%20Yesodei%20HaTorah&lang2=en):

> The retribution mentioned in the Torah is collective and individual — to the people in general and to each Israelite in particular. To the people in general — for open transgressions; and to each individual — for those committed in secret. For the will of the Giver of the Torah was to make all of Israel responsible for one another, this being a potent means of impeding the spread of subversion and corruption in the people. For, G-dly retribution being to the people collectively, it follows that if one sees his neighbor corrupting his ways, he will not say "What business is it of mine?", but he will reprove him. And if he continues sinning, he will testify against him in beth-din, which will punish him. "And all the people will hear and fear." Therefore, the blessings and curses (in the Torah) are to the nation in general.

So, to summarize the mefarshim mentioned above. The **hidden things** refer to sins that are committed in the privacy of one's home, as the Chizkuni wrote. Other people won't see that a person sins, and won't be able to reprimand. However, the revealed things, e.g. sins that were commited in public, people are able to reprimand one another for that.

Comment: I had not looked at it from that angle, I always learned that they referred to things that people are not allowed to know, that we had to settle for what was given and revealed to us, I consider this thought to be very Christian. Anyway, the answer is satisfactory

Comment: Happy to oblige! Please let me know if you need anything else. Ps. That could be an alternative explanation. But most of mefarshim say it refers to sinning in private and in public.

Comment: I intend to ask more questions but I think they are questions that would not need a separate topic, is there a space where I can discuss general questions without having to ask so many open questions in the forum? I'm relatively new to this space. I am embarrassed to create several questions one after the other

Comment: No need to be embarrassed. This forum is intended to ask questions :) To prevent that the scope of a question gets to big, I would recommend keep asking separate questions :).

Comment: For example, in the comments over time you can continue the discussion in a separate chat, is there a chat where things are discussed that are not done separately like here? If not, that's okay, I'll keep the questions right here.

Comment: @Thales start a chat room. I'll join when I can

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can start a chat if you want. Click here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=judaism.stackexchange.com and then click on create a new room (bottom).

Comment: That's really good. I'll take it easy to see the rules before creating.